# extract consecutive numbers along with its corresponding values from a list of runs of sequence numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want to groupby multiple repeats of consecutive numbers in a list of tuples.

```
import more_itertools as mit    
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4], 'b':[2,10,24,56,90,1,3,6]})
for group in mit.consecutive _groups(df['a'])
print(list(group)
```

I am getting output as

```
[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

My desired output is

```
[(0,2),(1,10),(2,24)],
[(0,56),(1,90),(2,1),(3,3),(4,6)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip the two sub-lists and use the `ordering` parameter with lambda function that returns the first item of the tuples in the zipped sequence:

```
for group in mit.consecutive_groups(zip(df['a'], df['b']), ordering=lambda t: t[0]):
    print(list(group))
```

This outputs:

```
[(0, 2), (1, 10), (2, 24)]
[(0, 56), (1, 90), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 6)]
```

Comment: thanks! may I know how to select each list, for example, [(0,2),(1,10),(2,24)] in group using index or any other ways? I tried with "print (list(map(itemgetter(1), group))), but I am getting " [ ] ".

Comment: You can convert the output of `consecutive_groups` to a list so that you can use an index to access any specific group at will: `groups = list(mit.consecutive_groups(zip(df['a'], df['b']), ordering=lambda t: t[0]))` and then access `groups[0]` for example.